# Soft input keyboard moves my static bottom view up Android Kotlin

Tags: android, keyboard, android-viewpager, android-softkeyboard, android-viewpager2

I have a Fragment with a static top view,a static bottom view and a ViewPager2 in the middle of those 2 views.(Look for Picture1 in the link provided). I have a problem when the keyboard shows up my bottom static view moves up. I tried all of android soft input methods and some code linked with that, some other code in stackoverflow but it doesn't work.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan" //does not work
```

[What i'm trying to do is hide that bottom static view like in Picture 2:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLQn0.png)

I archived what I was looking with this code:

```
 binding.parentConstrint.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
            val r = Rect()
            binding.parentConstrint.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r)
            val screenHeight = binding.parentConstrint.rootView.height
            val keypadHeight = screenHeight - r.bottom
            if (keypadHeight > screenHeight * 0.15) {
                if (!isKeyboardShowing) {
                    isKeyboardShowing = true
                    binding.bottomView.gone()
                }
            }else {
                if (isKeyboardShowing) {
                    isKeyboardShowing = false
                    binding.bottomView.visible()
                }
            }
        }
```

But this kinda refreshes my whole View when that bottom view appears and disappears and i can **see that refresh happening with my eyes**. Any ideas how to stop that refresh or to do this in another way?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the layout listener and use:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustNothing"
```

Otherwise try to remove this last line too from manifest

Comment: post the layout, it might be useful

Comment: i can't post it. But its like this

`-> ConstraintLayout
---->RelativeLayout(topview) i tried Constraint too.
---->ViewPager2
---->ConstraintLayout(bottomView)
->/Constraint `